# How can I access the internal phone storage via ClockworkMod recovery?

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, htc-droid-incredible, system-freeze, miui

I have an HTC Incredible, rooted to MIUI, and am frozen on the white Incredible boot screen. I need to grab a few pictures off the phone before I do a new install. Is it possible to access the phone memory from ClockworkMod recovery? I tried to mount the '/emmc' from the recovery prompt, but nothing shows up on the PC. How can I access the photos?

Comment: Have you tried using ADB? (The shell or `pull`)

Comment: I believe in CWM if you mount /sdcard you will be able to get to the internal storage. /emmc is external storage.

Answer (score 4):

/emmc is basically ok and accessible if you can 'mount' it. You already have a working CWM installed which comes with adb enabled. This gives you some options.
Boot to CWM recovery and mount your partition in the 'mounts and storage' section. It's now accessible internally and you can use the adb tool (ADB stands for 'Android debug bridge', it's usually used to develop and debug things) to pull data off the device:

- A windows tool (sadly discontinued): http://code.google.com/p/adb-file-explorer/
- by commandline: `adb pull /path/to/folder` or `adb pull /` to pull all currently mounted data partitions
- Another GUI: http://sourceforge.net/projects/adbbrowser/?source=recommended

PS: I prefer the command line adb tool (2nd solution). I have little experience with the gui tools. But generally they should work as well.

Here's how I usually do it (using only the commandline):

`me@workstation:~$ adb shell

~ # mount

rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)

tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,mode=755)

devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,mode=600)

proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)

sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)

/dev/block/mtdblock4 on /cache type yaffs2 (rw,nodev,noatime,nodiratime)

~ # mount /sdcard

~ # exit

me@workstation:~$ cd /tmp/

me@workstation:/tmp$ mkdir htc_sdcard

me@workstation:/tmp$ adb pull /sdcard/DCIM/100MSDCF/ htc_sdcard/DCIM

pull: building file list...

pull: /sdcard/DCIM/100MSDCF/DSC00110.jpg -> htc_sdcard/DCIM/DSC00110.jpg

pull: /sdcard/DCIM/100MSDCF/DSC00114.jpg -> htc_sdcard/DCIM/DSC00114.jpg

[...]`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the same on your phone, but on my Blade I can just mount /sdcard (or maybe /emmc in your case) and then "mount USB storage" in the Mount and Storage Menu.

Answer (score 0):

Your pictures should be stored on your SD card, so just take it out and get the pictures with a PC.

Comment: He could have had his pictures on his internal memory too.. maybe he's not talking about camera photos.